# Question Regarding Telescopic Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I find a formula for the partial sum $s_n$ for the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2})$$

Comment: Did you try to compute $s_n$ for some values of $n$, to see what happens?

Comment: You sum turns out to be$$\dfrac{n(3n+5)}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: @Ale Yep!${}{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**
Limit the sum by some $N$ and separate it, changing the index:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+2} \right)
 = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k+2}
 = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} - \sum_{k=3}^{N+2} \frac{1}{k}
$$
can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

For example: $$\left(\dfrac{1}{1} - \dfrac{1}{3}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{5}\right) = 
\dfrac{1}{1} + \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{5}$$
Try a few more: do you see the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to figure out the cancellations happening in

$$f(1) {\color{red}{- f(3)}} + f(2) \color{blue}{- f(4)} \color{red}{+ f(3)} \color{blue}{- f(4)} +\cdots\\+f(n-2) - f(n) + f(n-1) - f(n+1) + f(n) - f(n+2)$$